# Pid file with wrong user/permission

Tags: permissions, pid, systemd

I'm getting this error from opendkim service:

> systemd[1]: opendkim.service: Can't open PID file
>   /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or
>   directory

The pidfile is created owned by root while the service runs as user opendkim. If I run: `chown opendkim /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid`, when I restart opendkim it changes back to root.

```
$ s ls -l /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 6 Jun 28 02:25 /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
```